# Excel 2010 IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please explain following IF statement (Microsoft Excel 2010).

```
=IF(I12=0,Table!D13,Table!D15)+0.5
```

Please also explain the evaluation.

Comment: Type "EXCEL 2010 IF statement" into google ....: see first hit!

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about the "Table!" part, what that means? Unable to find a solution via googling. :(

Comment: Its a sheet name in your workbook

Comment: ok, then what Table!D13,Table!D15 means?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-change-a-cell-reference-HP010102343.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it just tests the cell `I12` whether it is equal to 0 - if it is, it gets the value of cell `D13` from the sheet `Table` (if not it gets `D15`) and then it sums this numeric value and `0.5`

it will give you a) the result or b) `#VALUE!` error if you try to add 0.5 to a text value

"On some computers, Excel or the operating system is set to use a comma as the decimal separator and a semicolon as the list separator." - http://www.treeplan.com/formula-you-typed-contains-error.htm - if that is your case, use `;` instead of `,` in your formula

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but where can I find D13 and D15, I am unable to locate these values. please help me find these values.

Comment: if you can't see the sheet, right-click on any sheet in lower right area of Excel and choose `Unhide sheet..`, then click on the sheet called `Table`, then see the cell in column `D`, row `13` - empty cells have a value of 0,, formulas have values of their results..

Comment: or see [where-are-my-worksheet-tabs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/where-are-my-worksheet-tabs-HA010278741.aspx) if you can't see the sheets tab ;)